# org.springframework.boot.web.support does not exist

Tags: java, maven, gradle, spring-boot

I'm changing build systems from maven to gradle for a spring boot project. I get this stacktrace

```
19:03:08: Executing external task 'bootRun'...
/home/dac/proj/spring-boot-master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp/src/main/java/sample/jetty/jsp/SampleJettyJspApplication.java:22: error: package org.springframework.boot.web.support does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
                                           ^
/home/dac/proj/spring-boot-master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp/src/main/java/sample/jetty/jsp/SampleJettyJspApplication.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
public class SampleJettyJspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
                                               ^
  symbol: class SpringBootServletInitializer
/home/dac/proj/spring-boot-master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp/src/main/java/sample/jetty/jsp/SampleJettyJspApplication.java:27: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
3 errors
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.334 secs
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
19:03:10: External task execution finished 'bootRun'.
```

My `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.6.RELEASE"
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.5.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'rebel'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.zeroturnaround', name: 'gradle-jrebel-plugin', version: '1.1.3'
    }
}
jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    // end::jetty[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("junit:junit")

}

// change default IntelliJ output directory for compiling classes
idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

My `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-samples</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring Boot Jetty JSP Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Jetty JSP Sample</description>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How should I make the package available to gradle?

Comment: Why both maven and gradle? Use one or the other not both.

Comment: Since this is a defect a Java source file, a clever IDE may be able to tell you exactly how to fix it: click-click-done.  Visual Studio Code did this for me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's probably an import issue in your source code - your Gradle build script uses Spring Boot 1.3.6.RELEASE in which SpringBootServletInitializer has the following fully qualified name:

```
org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
```

Your Maven pom.xml, however, uses Spring Boot 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, in which the package name was changed to:

```
org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
```

So if you go to your SampleJettyJspApplication and change the import to

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
```

everything should be fine.

Alternatively, you could alter your Gradle build script to import 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, but that would require adding Spring's snapshot repository:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven.url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot"
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Where does Spring has mentioned in the doc?

Comment: "All classes in the org.springframework.boot.context.web package have been deprecated and relocated."

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#deprecations-in-spring-boot-14

Answer (score 42):

You are using `org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer` this is deprecated. Instead:

## Use

`org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer`

#### For SpringBoot 2.0

`org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer`

Answer (score 3):

You should use the same spring boot version 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT as in maven. `org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer` was introduced since 1.4.0 that's why gradle cannot find it.

Comment: I failed adding the dependency `classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"` gradle could not reconfigure

Comment: That's because 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is located only in Spring's snapshot repository and not in Maven central, take a look at my answer for a code sample.

Comment: Add spring repos to gradle as @Miloš suggested. Spring Boot Gradle plugin documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score -2):

```java
org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
```

is deprecated.

use below instead:

```java
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
```