# Gradle + Spring Boot + Jetty + JSP fails

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot, jetty

I'm trying to use [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) with the [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) build system and [[image]jetty](/questions/tagged/jetty). Now the jsp doesn't render and i get this error msg

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jul 17 00:31:05 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceImports
```

it seems to depend on the build.gradle file.

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.6.RELEASE"
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.5.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'rebel'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.zeroturnaround', name: 'gradle-jrebel-plugin', version: '1.1.3'
    }
}
jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    // end::jetty[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api")
    compile('org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp')
    compile('org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp')

    runtime 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api'
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl'

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    testCompile("junit:junit")

}

// change default IntelliJ output directory for compiling classes
idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

If I use maven then I can render jsp if I start it from the command line with `mvn jetty:run`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-samples</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring Boot Jetty JSP Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Jetty JSP Sample</description>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Why even mix the build system with the runtime and why must I manually put together a jetty server just to run some jsp and servlets? I don't understand why Java project must make the easy thing impossible. It used to be easy to use jsp and servlet, now if I want to use jsp then I get 2 problems for one for several days.

Isn't there even a working example with gradle for this type of task? Do you know anything about what I'm trying to do at all?

Viewing a JSP with Jetty should be the most basic thing, why would I want to achieve something else with a Java server? Nobody uses Jetty for static content only or for RestAPI only - Jetty's main function is viewing JSP so why make the easy task impossible?

I also do web development with python and with python this type of problem is incomprenehsible - viewing a template just works and we couldn't achieve this type of problem even if we tried. Now Java has wasted my entire weekend with bad or no instructions, faulty build files and incomplete projects. I wished I stayed with C, assembly and python. At least we can debug things there and we have alternatives. Every time I try something with Java we get this problem, a puke of endless confusing stacktrace where you have to link to most obscure 4 gigabytes of jar and xml hell. I'm going back to assembly programming where can know what you're doing and you don't need 4 gigabytes of XML just to run a server which is only a source of confusion.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceImports
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1305) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224) ~[websocket-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:281) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceImports
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.findClass(JasperLoader.java:232) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:193) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:125) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:656) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:202) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595) [jetty-security-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:191) ~[jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:72) ~[jetty-server-9.2.17.v20160517.jar:9.2.17.v20160517]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1246) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1029) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
        ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceImports
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:187) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:125) ~[javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
        ... 92 common frames omitted
```

My file structure is

```
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/p/s/s/spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp> tree
.
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   ├── application.properties
│   │   │   ├── rebel.xml
│   │   │   └── sample
│   │   │       └── jetty
│   │   │           └── jsp
│   │   │               ├── MyException.class
│   │   │               ├── MyRestResponse.class
│   │   │               ├── SampleJettyJspApplication.class
│   │   │               └── WelcomeController.class
│   │   └── test
│   ├── dependency-cache
│   ├── libs
│   │   ├── gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
│   │   └── gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar.original
│   ├── resources
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── application.properties
│   │       └── rebel.xml
│   └── tmp
│       ├── compileJava
│       │   └── emptySourcePathRef
│       ├── compileTestJava
│       │   └── emptySourcePathRef
│       └── jar
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle
├── build.log
├── classes
│   └── production
│       └── spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp
│           ├── application.properties
│           └── rebel.xml
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── pom.xml
├── spring
│   ├── gradle
│   │   └── wrapper
│   │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│   │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
│   ├── gradlew
│   ├── gradlew.bat
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   │   └── sample
│       │   │       └── jetty
│       │   │           └── jsp
│       │   │               ├── MyException.java
│       │   │               ├── MyRestResponse.java
│       │   │               ├── SampleJettyJspApplication.java
│       │   │               └── WelcomeController.java
│       │   ├── resources
│       │   │   ├── application.properties
│       │   │   └── rebel.xml
│       │   └── webapp
│       │       └── WEB-INF
│       │           └── jsp
│       │               └── welcome.jsp
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── sample
│                   └── jetty
│                       └── jsp
│                           └── SampleWebJspApplicationTests.java
├── spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp.iml
├── spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp.ipr
├── spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp.iws
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── sample
│   │   │       └── jetty
│   │   │           └── jsp
│   │   │               ├── MyException.java
│   │   │               ├── MyRestResponse.java
│   │   │               ├── SampleJettyJspApplication.java
│   │   │               └── WelcomeController.java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   ├── application.properties
│   │   │   └── rebel.xml
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           └── jsp
│   │               └── welcome.jsp
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── sample
│               └── jetty
│                   └── jsp
│                       └── SampleWebJspApplicationTests.java
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   ├── application.properties
    │   ├── rebel.xml
    │   └── sample
    │       └── jetty
    │           └── jsp
    │               ├── MyException.class
    │               ├── MyRestResponse.class
    │               ├── SampleJettyJspApplication.class
    │               └── WelcomeController.class
    ├── generated-sources
    │   └── annotations
    ├── generated-test-sources
    │   └── test-annotations
    ├── maven-archiver
    │   └── pom.properties
    ├── maven-status
    │   └── maven-compiler-plugin
    │       ├── compile
    │       │   └── default-compile
    │       │       ├── createdFiles.lst
    │       │       └── inputFiles.lst
    │       └── testCompile
    │           └── default-testCompile
    │               ├── createdFiles.lst
    │               └── inputFiles.lst
    ├── spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
    │   ├── META-INF
    │   └── WEB-INF
    │       ├── classes
    │       │   ├── application.properties
    │       │   ├── rebel.xml
    │       │   └── sample
    │       │       └── jetty
    │       │           └── jsp
    │       │               ├── MyException.class
    │       │               ├── MyRestResponse.class
    │       │               ├── SampleJettyJspApplication.class
    │       │               └── WelcomeController.class
    │       ├── jsp
    │       │   └── welcome.jsp
    │       └── lib
    │           ├── classmate-1.3.1.jar
    │           ├── hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar
    │           ├── jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
    │           ├── jackson-core-2.8.0.jar
    │           ├── jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar
    │           ├── jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
    │           ├── jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar
    │           ├── jstl-1.2.jar
    │           ├── jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar
    │           ├── log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar
    │           ├── logback-classic-1.1.7.jar
    │           ├── logback-core-1.1.7.jar
    │           ├── slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
    │           ├── snakeyaml-1.17.jar
    │           ├── spring-aop-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-beans-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-boot-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-boot-starter-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-boot-starter-logging-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-boot-starter-validation-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-boot-starter-web-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-context-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-core-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-expression-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-web-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           ├── spring-webmvc-4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │           └── validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
    ├── spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
    ├── spring-boot-sample-jetty-jsp-1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war.original
    ├── surefire-reports
    │   ├── sample.jetty.jsp.SampleWebJspApplicationTests.txt
    │   └── TEST-sample.jetty.jsp.SampleWebJspApplicationTests.xml
    └── test-classes
        └── sample
            └── jetty
                └── jsp
                    └── SampleWebJspApplicationTests.class

85 directories, 95 files
```

Comment: please show the structure tree of your project.

Comment: Why do you have a pom.xml file and a build.gradle file and why do you have different dependencies configured in each of them?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I'm trying to change build system from maven to gradle in order to learn gradle. Should I give up and use maven instead? It works with maven and I wanted to make it work with gradle. I also tried making a `gradle init` to traslate the `pom.xml` but that failed directly.

Comment: what is your gradle command line to you run your app ?

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte `gradle bootRun` and it makes a stacktrace when I hit the JSP.

Comment: Let’s engage spring-boot-gradle-plugin by launching the app with Gradle:
 ./gradlew clean bootRun OR (omit the ./) like this : gradlew clean bootRun

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte Still the same error when I hit the JSP: `Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceImports`

Comment: Sorry but in my opinion this is an IntelliJ related issue. try building a new spring-boot web app. The most straightforward way to use the Spring Initializr is to point your web browser to http://start.spring.io.

Comment: It isn't an IntelliJ issue, it's a [known issue with Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the issues you are experiencing are not **Java** problem, they are Spring Boot issues. Spring Boot is an opinionated convention-over-configuration framework that comes from Spring and it's supposed to make your life easier... if you know what you're doing with it, which most people without prior Spring experience really don't (completely understandably, I must add).

What Spring Boot does is scan your classpath, see what dependencies you have in your project, see what manual configuration you've provided and then decide what other configuration options to include automatically.

Why you have to involve Maven into running your application? Well, simply because you declared the packaging to be **`war`**, which tells Spring Boot that you want to be able to deploy the file to a web server, instead of running it with an embedded Jetty. `mvn jetty:run` does exactly that - it starts a Jetty server and deploys your application to it. You could do this manually on an existing Jetty but for development purposes it's much faster this way.

As far your problem at hand goes, this is a [known issue](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) and it is still not possible to have JAR packaging - and your Gradle script is using JAR packaging - with Spring Boot applications that want to do JSP templating. (I would, however, recommend using [Thymeleaf](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)).

But if you still wish to do Gradle + Jetty + JSP, please [make sure you set your packaging to `war`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging)

Comment: Ok I can switch to tomcat, but I'm surprised that jetty has issues. When I learn Thymeleaf then maybe I can make it work with jetty?

Comment: JSPs in general are problematic, especially with JAR packaging, which is what you're using in Gradle

Comment: And yes, Thymeleaf should work fine with any embedded server, really, and also in your integration tests

Comment: Also, see my answer on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413594/org-springframework-boot-web-support-does-not-exist), you may need to use Spring Boot 1.4.0 in your Gradle build, I'm not sure when the fix for JSPs was added.